# Jenkins Shared Library: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline through Jenkinsfile with Shared Libraries. I created a job through the Web UI to get the Jenkinsfile, which is working ok. However, the shared library content do not seems to be recognizable by Jenkins. Below are the Jenkinsfile and the shared library content and the console error. I double checked the Jenkins general config (where the shared library scm is set) and the Pipeline plugin installation. Don't know where else to go.

Shared Library Content

```
# var/log.groovy

def call(String name = 'human') {
  echo "Hello, ${name}."
}
```

Jenkinsfile Content

```
# Jenkinsfile

@Library('jenkinstest') _

node {
    log("User!")
}
```

Log Error

```
Loading library jenkinstest@master
Attempting to resolve master from remote references...
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Gitlab ssh key
 > /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t #############/jenkinstest.git # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/master revision #############
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from git@##############/jenkinstest.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Gitlab ssh key
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --progress git@##############/jenkinstest.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision ############# (master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f #############
Commit message: "fix on groovy"
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk ############# # timeout=10
[Pipeline] node
Running on jenkins-node3 in /Users/admin/jenkins-home/workspace/automation-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'log' found among steps [acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, ansiColor, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, gitlabBuilds, gitlabCommitStatus, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, powershell, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, slackSend, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, task, throttle, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash, updateGitlabCommitStatus, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, bitbucket, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildParameter, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changelog, changeset, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, command, compressBuildLog, configFile, configFileProvider, copyArtifacts, credentials, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, environment, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, gitLabConnection, github, githubPush, gitlab, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, label, lastCompleted, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, lastSuccessful, latestSavedBuild, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, nunit, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameterizedCron, parameters, password, pattern, permalink, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, remotingCLI, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, specific, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, workspace, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, manager, params, pipeline, scm]
```

Comment: What happens if you `import log` underneath the `@Library`?

Comment: What is your git repo setup. You have a subfolder var or `vars`? In every example they have the folder vars instead of var in which they put their scripts. I think it's really necessary that it's called vars.

Comment: Attempted both and renaming directory "var" to "vars" was the solution, even though Jenkins documentation uses "var". Thanks a lot @lvthillo

Comment: @FelyppeRodrigues No problem. I've written it down as an answer. Please accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename your `var/` folder in git to `vars/`. In this folder you can store your groovy scripts.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

`@Library('jenkinstest') _
new var.log.call(name)`